# Avoid images to be processed by the thumbnail service

Tags: android, image, thumbnails

I am building an application that downloads images from the web to the SD Card and then displays them conveniently. The application also generates thumbnails for those pictures. Problem is that those images and their generated thumbnails are indexed by the Media service and for instance appear in the gallery.

Furthermore, that system service consumes lots of CPU when generating its own thumbnails.

Is there a way to tell that system service that I don't want my pictures to appear in the gallery and that it should not generate thumbnails for my images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an empty `.nomedia` file in the directory where your images reside.