# How do I load an image in the gallery app given an `R.drawable.foo` reference?

Tags: android

If I have this in hand:

```
R.drawable.foo
```

Which is really just a reference to a jpg file, how do I open it in Android's gallery app?

I have found a bunch of references which suggest something along the lines of this:

```
startActivity(
    new Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  
        /* what goes here for the URI?? */
    )
);
```

But what URI do I use?

I'm doing [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) and want to open the images in the native Android app when tapped so I can get all that zooming, sharing, etc. for free.

If I can't use a URI here (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307374/need-suggestion-about-a-mixed-uri-int-id-images-ambient)), what should I do to load the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by design other applications cannot access your resources. its the same the otherway.

so you have two options.

**Easyway:**

**copy your resource (manualy)** to the sdcard and then sent the uri

this is how your URI might look

```
Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/android/com.my.app/.cache/foo.jpg");
```

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` abstracts hard coding or mount
the `.cache` will be a hidden folder and if you don't want your temp image to show up in gallery images then you need to create a [.nomedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110774/avoid-images-to-be-processed-by-the-thumbnail-service) empty file in the `.cache` folder

you might need to add the sdcard permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**the Hardway:**

your need to implement a [FileContentProvider](http://code.google.com/p/rowanandroid/source/browse/trunk/Rowan/src/rowan/application/quickaccess/FileContentProvider.java?spec=svn6&r=6) using a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

supply you custom URI and supply your file from your FileContentProvider.Open, you may need to implement `mime` and other methods aswell for this

**UPDATE**
you may also need to register your content provider in the manifest.
[Android - open pdf in external application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129038/android-open-pdf-in-external-application/5442250#5442250)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! If I copy them to the SD card, what then is the recommended call to launch them (i.e. the full `startactivity` call)?

Comment: What's the typical way an app loads resources into its `.cache` folder? Does this need to be coded up or do I put my files in a special location and they get dropped there on install?

Comment: the /sdcard/com.my.app path is created in newer version of android but in 2.1 and 2.2 i guess we have to create it. and the drawable we have to copy manually